# Installing ZLIB in Linux Server

Tags: linux, zlib

I want to install [ZLIB](http://www.techsww.com/tutorials/libraries/zlib/installation/installing_zlib_on_ubuntu_linux.php) in the Linux server. My server account is: /home/myname . I download and extract ZLIB on my account properly. Then, I enter to ZLIB1.2.6 folder and run the command:

> ./configure --prefix=/home/myname/zlib

But, it gives error:

> -bash: ./configure: Permission denied

Can anybody help me why is this happening ?

Comment: Any particular reason for not installing the zlib that comes with your distro?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, can you kindly inform me, is there any mistake in commands ? Sorry, I have very little idea about Linux.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, if you are using Debian, you should do:

```
su
```

to become root

```
apt-get update
```

to refresh the package lists, then

```
apt-cache search zlib
```

to check the relevant packages in the lists you have just updated, then

```
apt-get install <whatever_package_you_found_earlier>
```

---

I suggest using regular expression as search strings for apt-cache, since they are more accurate, as in

```
apt-cache search ^zlib
```

to return only package names *starting* with zlib

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo apt-get install libgcrypt11-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: While this may solve OP's problem, it gives very little insight in the problem, or why this solves the problem. Please elaborate on your solution

Answer (score 4):

As Ignacio wrote above, just install the package for your particular distribution unless there is a very, very specific reason why you need that particular version of zlib.

Comment: Sorry. I do not get your point. To install that what commands, I have to run. I have very less idea about Linux. Sorry.

Comment: What distribution (Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS, RedHat, etc) are you running? Once you figure that out, do some google searches about how to install software for your distribution. They generally all come with some form of package management which means installing new software that is in the package repository very quick and easy.

Comment: Thanks a lot. BTW, I am using Debian Linux.

Comment: you'll be using apt-get, or aptitude or another similar tool to do the package management & install. See http://www.debian.org/doc/user-manuals and http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html