# Can someone please show me how to enable php to use zlib compression

Tags: php, symfony

It has been two days now. I want to start a course on symfony2 framework but I cannot continue because of this problem.

[image: Error]

Comment: The error is barely visible, please copy paste the text output directly in the question?

Comment: I believe it's > _Fatal error : uncaught exception 'Phar Exception' with message 'zlib extension is required for gz compressed .phar file /usr/local/bin/Symfony' in /usr/local/bin/symfony:9_.   I think this can help OP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047876/symfony-zlib-extension-missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install zlib

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall zlibc zlib1g zlib1g-dev
```

refer details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979870/installing-zlib-in-linux-server) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1528204)

You can add the option --with-zlib --with-zlib=DIR when you configure your php to enable the zlib.

Example:

```
php_5.6.7$ ./configure --with-zlib --with-zlib=DIR
```

Refer above details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047876/symfony-zlib-extension-missing)

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're runnning Ubuntu.

Just open your terminal and run:

`sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`